# Angular JS reloading whole body when clicked on Other Tabs

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

My web page has 3 bootstrap tabs with data some data being populated run time. After page loads, tab1 looks fine and when I click on other tabs, whole body reloads and tab1 displays. I do not see any errors in Console.

[image: Bootstrap Tabs]

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>


<div class="container" -ng-controller="incidentSummaryCtrl" >
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Incident  {{c.data.incidentData[0].incidentId}} </h3> </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
            <div class="panel-group">


                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <h1 class="white"></h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
                                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Section1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Incident Information</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#Section2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Potential Indicators</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#Section3" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Course of Action</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- Tab panes -->
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="Section1">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                       <p><label>First Name: </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].firstName}}    </p>
                                        <p><label>Last Name: </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].lastName}}      </p>
                                        <p><label>Email: </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].email}}      </p>
                                        <p><label>Telephone Number: </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].telephoneNumber}}      </p>
                                        <p><label>Reported Date:  </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].createdDate}}   </p>
                                        <p><label>Last Updated:  </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].lastUpdated}}   </p>  
                                      </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                                        <p><label>Incident #: </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].incidentId}}    </p>
                                        <p><label>Status: </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].incidentStatus}}      </p>
                                        <p><label>Category: </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].incidentType}}      </p>
                                        <p><label>Organization:  </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].organization}}   </p>
                                        <p><label>Department:  </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].department}}   </p>
                                        <p><label>Assigned To:  </label> {{c.data.incidentData[0].assignedTo}} </p>
                                      </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <p><label for="notes">Notes:</label>   </p>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="notes" ng-readonly="true">{{c.data.incidentData[0].note}}</textarea>
                                      </div>

                                    </div> <!-- End of Section1 -->


                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section2">
                                        <label>Extracted Potential Indicators</label>
                                        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>No</th>
                                                <th>Ranking</th>
                                                <th>Indicator</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="indicator in c.data.indicatorsData track by $index" >
                                                <td>{{indicator.number}}</td>
                                                <td>{{indicator.urgencyRanking}}</td>
                                                <td>{{indicator.indicatorText}}</td>
                                                <td class="{{indicator.cssClass}}"><a href="https://dev21310.service-now.com/haloportal/?id=potential_indicator_summary&indicator_id={{indicator.sysId}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click here to see more information">{{indicator.indicatorStatus}}</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div> <!-- End of Section2 -->


                                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Section3">
                                        <p><label>Recommendation: </label> {{c.data.courseOfActionsData[0].recommendedName}}   </p>
                                        <p><label>Reasoning: </label> {{c.data.courseOfActionsData[0].reasoning}}  </p>

                                        <p><label>Select Course of Action: </label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="selectedValue"  style="max-width:700px">
                                                <option ng-repeat="coa in c.data.ListOfCourseOfActionsData track by $index" value="{{coa.name}}" ng-selected="{{defaultvalue == c.data.courseOfActionsData[0].recommendedName}}">{{coa.name}}</option>
                                            </select> </p>

                                        <p><label>Additional Actions: </label>   </p>
                                        <div id="actions">
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="sendEmailUpdateToReporter">Send Email Update to Reporter</label>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="notifyIsp" ng-model="notifyIsp">Notify ISP</label>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="notifyDomainRegistrar" ng-model="notifyDomainRegistrar">Notify Domain Registrar</label> <br/>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="sendEmailReceipt">Send Email Receipt to Reporter</label>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="setStatusOfTicketToResolved">Set Status of Ticket Resolved
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="notifyProduction">Notify Production</label><br/>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="resolveAndCloseTicket">Resolve and Close Ticket</label>
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-model="checked" id="assignToGroup">Assign to Group</label>
                                            <br/>
                                        </div> <br/>


                                        <div class="row">

                                            <div id="assignment" class="col-md-4">
                                                <b>Group Name:</b>
                                                <select  id="groupSelectedValue" ng-model="groupSelectedValue"  style="max-width:700px"    class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="Tier1">Tier1</option>
                                                    <option value="Tier2">Tier2</option>
                                                    <option value="Tier3">Tier3</option>
                                                    <option value="Tier4">Tier4</option>
                                                    <option value="Tier5">Tier5</option>
                                                    <option value="Halo Administrator">Halo Administrator</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                <b>Assign To:</b>
                                                <select  id="assignTo" ng-model="assignTo"    style="max-width:700px"  class="form-control" >
                                                    <option  ng-repeat="user in (c.data.groupUsers | filter: {'groupName':groupSelectedValue}) track by $index" value="user.name">{{user.name}}</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <br/>

                                    <div id="commentsSection" >
                                        <div class="">
                                         <span ng-hide="c.data.incidentData[0].incidentStatus == 'Closed'">
                                           <b>Comments:</b>  <textarea id="comments"  class="form-control"  ng-model="comments"> </textarea> <br/>
                                         </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <br/>

                                        <div class="">
                                            <b>Comments History: </b>
                                            <table class="table table-responsive">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Comment </th>
                                                    <th>Entered Date </th>
                                                    <th>Entered By </th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="text in c.data.commentshistory track by $index">
                                                    <td>{{text.comment}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{text.enteredDate}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{text.enteredBy}}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>

                                            </table>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="execute()">Execute</button>
                                            <input type="hidden" id="sysId" value="{{sysId}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> <!-- End of Section3 -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End of Container -->




        </div> <!--End of Panel Group -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Angular JS Code:

```
(function()
{
    "use strict";
    var app=angular.module('indicatorModal',[]);
    app.controller('incidentSummaryCtrl',['$scope',function($scope)
    {

        $scope.updateSelectedCoa=function()
        {
            //get Values from Form
            var selectedCoa=jQuery("#sel1 option:selected").text();
            var sendEmailUpdateToReporter=jQuery("#sendEmailUpdateToReporter").is(":checked");
            var notifyIsp=jQuery("#notifyIsp").is(":checked");
            var notifyDomainRegistrar=jQuery("#notifyDomainRegistrar").is(":checked");
            var sendEmailReceipt=jQuery("#sendEmailReceipt").is(":checked");
            var setStatusOfTicketToResolved=jQuery("#setStatusOfTicketToResolved").is(":checked");
            var notifyProduction=jQuery("#notifyProduction").is(":checked");
            var assignToNextTier=jQuery("#assignToNextTier").is(":checked");
            var assignToGroup=jQuery("#assignToGroup").is(":checked");
            var resolveAndCloseTicket=jQuery("#resolveAndCloseTicket").is(":checked");
            var sysId=jQuery("#sysId").val();


            var gr=new GlideRecord('x_19668_halo_incident');
            gr.addQuery('sys_id',sysId);
            gr.query(callbackFunction);
            function callbackFunction(gr)
            {
                if(gr.next())
                    {
                    $scope.updateSelectedSysIdOfCoa(selectedCoa,sysId);
                    gr.send_email_update_to_reporter=sendEmailUpdateToReporter;
                    gr.notify_isp=notifyIsp;
                    gr.send_email_receipt_to_reporter=sendEmailReceipt;
                    gr.set_status_to_resolved=setStatusOfTicketToResolved;
                    gr.notify_production=notifyProduction;
                    gr.notify_domain_registrar=notifyDomainRegistrar;
                    gr.assign_to_tier=assignToNextTier;
                    gr.assign_to_group=assignToGroup;
                    gr.resolve_and_close_the_ticket=resolveAndCloseTicket;
                    gr.update();
                }
            }

        };



        $scope.updateSelectedSysIdOfCoa=function(selectedCoa,sysId)
        {
            var selectedCoaSysId='';
            var gr1=new GlideRecord('x_19668_halo_selcted_ticket_course_of_action');
            gr1.addQuery('incident_id',sysId);
            gr1.query(callbackFunction2);
            function callbackFunction2(gr1)
            {
                if(gr1.next())
                    {
                    var gr2=new GlideRecord('x_19668_halo_courseofactions');
                    gr2.addQuery('ticket_coa_name',selectedCoa);
                    gr2.query();
                    if(gr2.next())
                        {
                        selectedCoaSysId=gr2.sys_id+'';
                    }
                    gr1.ticket_coa_selected_id=selectedCoaSysId;
                    gr1.update();

                }
            }

        };

        $scope.passSysId=function(indicatorSysId,indicatorType)
        {
            var ipIndicatorsData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('ipIndicatorsData'));
            var domainIndicatorsData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('domainIndicatorsData'));
            var hashCodeIndicatorsData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('hashCodeIndicatorsData'));
            if(indicatorType == 'IP Address')
                {
                for(var indicator in ipIndicatorsData )
                    {
                    if(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].sysId == indicatorSysId)
                        {
                        jQuery("#indicatorId").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorId);
                        jQuery("#indicatorStatus").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorStatus);
                        jQuery("#indicatorType").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorType);
                        jQuery("#urgencyRanking").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].urgencyRanking);
                        jQuery("#completedEnrichCount").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].completedEnrichCount);
                        jQuery("#enrichStartTimestamp").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichStartTimestamp);
                        jQuery("#enrichEndTimestamp").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichEndTimestamp);
                        jQuery("#indicatorText").text(ipIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorText);
                        $("#indicatorLink").attr("href", "https://dev21310.service-now.com/haloportal/?id=potential_indicator_summary&indicator_id="+indicatorSysId);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(indicatorType == 'Full Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)')
                {
                for(var indicator in domainIndicatorsData )
                    {
                    if(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].sysId == indicatorSysId)
                        {
                        jQuery("#indicatorId").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorId);
                        jQuery("#indicatorStatus").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorStatus);
                        jQuery("#indicatorType").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorType);
                        jQuery("#urgencyRanking").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].urgencyRanking);
                        jQuery("#completedEnrichCount").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].completedEnrichCount);
                        jQuery("#enrichStartTimestamp").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichStartTimestamp);
                        jQuery("#enrichEndTimestamp").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichEndTimestamp);
                        jQuery("#indicatorText").text(domainIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorText);
                        jQuery("#indicatorLink").attr("href", "https://dev21310.service-now.com/haloportal/?id=potential_indicator_summary&indicator_id="+indicatorSysId);

                    }
                }
            }
            else if(indicatorType == 'Hash Code')
                {
                for(var indicator in hashCodeIndicatorsData )
                    {
                    if(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].sysId == indicatorSysId)
                        {
                        jQuery("#indicatorId").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorId);
                        jQuery("#indicatorStatus").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorStatus);
                        jQuery("#indicatorType").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorType);
                        jQuery("#urgencyRanking").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].urgencyRanking);
                        jQuery("#completedEnrichCount").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].completedEnrichCount);
                        jQuery("#enrichStartTimestamp").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichStartTimestamp);
                        jQuery("#enrichEndTimestamp").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].enrichEndTimestamp);
                        jQuery("#indicatorText").text(hashCodeIndicatorsData[indicator].indicatorText);
                        $("#indicatorLink").attr("href", "https://dev21310.service-now.com/haloportal/?id=potential_indicator_summary&indicator_id="+indicatorSysId);
                    }
                }

            }


        };

    }]);

})();
```

Comment: the "-" before ng-controller have anything to do with it?

Comment: Nah. It's part of the syntax in ServiceNow application.

Comment: Are there any other scripts that are scanning for A links and appending url's to the href? It sounds like when you click the tab it's taking you to the link instead of opening the ui.

Comment: No. Each has it's own section as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Angular UI instead of bootstrap

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I tried this. It solves my problem and creates another problem. Tabs are not being rendered even HTML when I load first time

Comment: By looking at some examples I am able to implement this in ui bootstrap